# JQuery/Ajax/JSon - Chegar até o JSon

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Tenho um array e preciso chegar até ele com jquery/ajax, o problema é que não sei como chegar até ele, ele está sendo criado por php `$json = Array();` depois faço um array push assim:

```
array_push($json, array(
    'nome'=>'teste'
));
```

e depois junto os arrays assim:

```
$result = array (
    $json,
    $json2,
    $json3
);
```

dando um console log usando o ajax, ele aparece dessa forma o json no chrome:

```
[Array[2]]
 0:Array[2]
  0:Object
   nome: "teste"
```

e no ajax o success está assim:

```
success: function (response) {
    console.log(response);
}
```

como chego até o `nome: "teste"`?
tentei assim mas não deu: `console.log(response.nome);`

EDIT: impressão do php:

```
[[{"nome":"teste"}]]
```

Comment: como esta imprimindo o array com o php?

Comment: editei e coloquei no post

Comment: var json = [[{"nome":"teste"}]];
        console.log(json[0][0].nome);   // faça um loop percorrendo cada array para verificar o tamanho para não perder informação e acessar dinamicamente...

Comment: vlw @GabrielRodrigues!